# Swift - How Can I Show The MKPolyline For A Tracked Event

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mapkit, mkpolyline

My problem is that when a jog has been completed, I can not present the recordedMapView with a full polyline that had tracked the location in an after exercise report.

Currently I am able to persist the data from tracking a run in the first view controller appearing in app, then in the detail view controller I fetch the data and unwrap/assign them to the respective variables, however, I am not sure where I go wrong in the code that is not allowing a polyline to appear. The map region does seem to be getting set properly as the map zooms in and out dynamically to fit the entire journey.

What could be the issue for why the polyline is not being presented and is there a solution to the code that I have provided to correct this problem?

```
var context : NSManagedObjectContext?

var runTimestamp      : NSDate?
var runDuration       : NSNumber?
var runDistance       : NSNumber?
var runLocations      : NSOrderedSet?

var locationTimeStamp : NSDate?
var locationLatitude  : NSNumber?
var locationLongitude : NSNumber?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let context = context, finishedLocations = fetchLocation ( context ), finishedRun = fetchRun ( context ) else { return }

    for location in finishedLocations
    {
        if let timestamp = location.timestamp, latitude = location.latitude, longitude = location.longitude
        {
            locationTimeStamp = timestamp
            locationLatitude  = latitude
            locationLongitude = longitude
        }
    }

    for run in finishedRun
    {
        if let timeStamp = run.timestamp, duration = run.duration, distance = run.distance, locations = run.locations
        {
            runTimestamp = timeStamp
            runDuration  = duration
            runDistance  = distance
            runLocations = locations
        }
    }

    updateUI      ()
} 

 func loadMapView()
{
    if runLocations!.count > 0
    {
        recordedMapView.region = mapRegion()
        let colorSegments      = MulticolorPolylineSegment.colorSegments(forLocations: runLocations!.array as! [Location])
        recordedMapView.addOverlays(colorSegments)
    }
    else
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController( title: "Error", message: "No Locations Saved", preferredStyle: .Alert )
        let alertAction     = UIAlertAction    ( title: "Error", style  : .Default            , handler       : nil    )
        alertController.addAction( alertAction                                      )
        presentViewController    ( alertController, animated: true, completion: nil )
    }
}

func mapRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion
{
    let initialLocation = runLocations!.firstObject as! Location

    var minLat = initialLocation.latitude! .doubleValue
    var minLng = initialLocation.longitude!.doubleValue
    var maxLat = minLat
    var maxLng = minLng

    let locations = runLocations!.array as! [Location]

    for location in locations
    {
        minLat = min( minLat, location.latitude! .doubleValue )
        minLng = min( minLng, location.longitude!.doubleValue )
        maxLat = max( maxLat, location.latitude! .doubleValue )
        maxLng = max( maxLng, location.longitude!.doubleValue )
    }

    return MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude     : ( (minLat + maxLat)/2  ) , longitude     : ( (minLng + maxLng)/2  ) ),
        span  : MKCoordinateSpan      ( latitudeDelta: ( (maxLat - minLat)*1.1) , longitudeDelta: ( (maxLng - minLng)*1.1) )
                             )
}

func polyline() -> MKPolyline
{
    var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    let locations   = runLocations!.array as! [Location]
    for location in locations
    {
        coordinates.append( CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location.latitude!.doubleValue), longitude: (location.longitude!.doubleValue)) )
    }
    return MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: runLocations!.count)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
{
    let polyline         = overlay as! MulticolorPolylineSegment
    let renderer         = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
    renderer.strokeColor = polyline.color
    renderer.lineWidth   = 3
    return renderer
}
```

Comment: Im still really lost as to why the data is not getting translated into the creation of a polyline. It could be a simple mistake on my end that I am not able to catch.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.x:
What I see you don't add the polyLine properly into mapView.

Change your polyline function like below;

```
func polyline()
{
    if theJourney != nil && theJourney!.coords != nil{
        var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        let locations   = runLocations!.array as! [Location]
        for location in locations
        {
            coordinates.append( CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location.latitude!.doubleValue), longitude: (location.longitude!.doubleValue)) )
        }
    }

    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: runLocations!.count)
    mapView.add(polyline)
}
```

And MKMapView's rendererFor method with code below;

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.green
            renderer.lineWidth = 3
            return renderer
}
```

That's should work. Please let me know.